Consent mode in GTM shows "region" in consent events
I am trying to implement Consent mode in GTM with Cookie pro. I see in the tag debugging that I have an event "region". What does it mean and where does it come from?
GTM screenshot
I have to 2 regions in Cookie pro settings - Global and EU. But I haven't defined region-specific behaviour in GTM.
